# Error loading multiple values on a SQL Table Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I'm with a project on Google maps, that I want to save routes and Waypoints on a map, the problem is that I can sabe the routes on the database, but can't load all of them on the map, I can only load one Route, and I want to load multiple routes.

For you undertand access this example:

Click on the map to create the start point, and click again to create the end point, them, click on save waypoints
This is my codes

index.htm

This is a print of my table
[image]

OBS: This is only a part of my code, to see the full code, please enter on the links that I sent and see the Source pressing CTRL+U

I really need help, I'm trying for one month on the same problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many 'errors' causing the problem

1. Database structure

1.1 Your table has only 1 field(column) holding all the data

1.2 As there is only 1 field how do you differentiate between routes?

At the the very least you should have at least 2 fields id(preferably autocomplete)and value. Allthough preferably you should have a field for each attribute.

2.
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($res,1);

The second parameter should be the type of array that is to be fetched. It's a constant and can take the following values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH. 
[see php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

As this parameter is not required try  $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res);

3.
Instead of

$query = "insert into inventoresdegara set value='$data'";

Try

$query = "INSERT INTO inventoresdegara  VALUE('$data')";

I would suggest you read up on using PHP/MySQL [w3 school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)