# Delete Markers from table on MySQL Google Maps v3

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I want to delete specific Markers from my database, I can save than with an "ID", I wan't to use the same ID to delete from database,

For example, if I save 20 waypoints, the id of each marker will be (1,2,3,...,20)

I want to use this value on JavaScript and delete a specific line from the table on PHP code,
For example, if I click on a marker on my project, it will automacally delete from map and from database, I have a code here:

**EDITED WITH MY TRY**

```
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, deleta) {

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);


  });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() 
       {    
           marker.setVisible(false) 
              alert(deleta)
              deleteMK(deleta)
    });


}

function deleteMK(deleta)
    {
        alert("vai");
         var url2 = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?deleta=" + deleta;   
    downloadUrl2(url2, function(data3, responseCode) 

    {
        if (responseText == 200 && data3.length <= 1) 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Deletado";
            window.location.reload()
        }
    });     
    }

    var string2 = JSON.stringify(data3)
//Função ajax que salva os marcadores no mapa
function downloadUrl2(url2, callback) 
{
    var request2 = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    request2.open('POST',url2);
    request2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request2.send('command=delete&marker='+string2)
    request2.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(request2.readyState==4) 
        {   
            //infowindow.close();
            alert('Deletado')

        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
$deleta = $_REQUEST['deleta]'];

    if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete')
{
    $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM markers WHERE id='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($deleta));



}
```

Comment: I can see an obvious error in your code, but you haven't asked a question. What is your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: @Marcelo, I edited the code, but I don't know why don't work, I want to call the value delete to php, like a variable for   DELETE FROM markers WHERE id='variable'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What ever you do don't use unescaped HTML in your query see [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp)

USE**

```
<?php  
 require("dbinfo.php");
// Get parameters from URL
 $id = $_GET["id"];
//Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
 if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// delete the row in the table
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM *your table* WHERE *your field name*
echo "<br>";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query);
 if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
 }
?>
```

You should also confirm delete in infobox

I assume you are now using ID column (atocomplete} as I suggested in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203187/error-loading-multiple-values-on-a-sql-table-google-maps)

Comment: Hey guy, I tried, updated my code but don't worked, I think my problem is on PHP, because all my alerts works, take a look on my edited code

Comment: I have had time to look at your code.I think you will need 2 different ajax calls. 1 to load markers and another to delete markers. I am working on this and will get back to you

Comment: Thank you guy, I will be waiting and trying too =), I have a ajax code for loady and one to delete markers, if you want, take a look on the project http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/loadyMK.html

Comment: My server is down just now so I cant show you where i am at. I have looked at loady but there is to much to change to run it on localhost. When I have finished I will load it onto my test site for you to see.

Comment: Still problems with server ftp. Have got it working with 2 Ajax calls

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16980/discussion-between-david-strachan-and-fred-vicentin)

Comment: Now worked guy, was a problem on PHP, it's not $_GET, is $_REQUEST, my wrong =/

Comment: Email me @ daviestrachan@yahoo.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

As long the ID of a Marker is something comum you can't simply use it in the normal way and as you need to delete it using the ID, you should try use date&time variable to set the ID to a Marker. This is something usefull in these situation, because time only moves forward.

Try to convert date and time of the momment you create the marker, to hours, minutes or seconds, and set it to Marker ID and use it as a FK of your marker in your DB.

Sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a poly line on driving mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1
/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<!--http://www.askdata.net/propmap/mapdata.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://Violette.com/MapFiles
/Icons.png');
//var side_bar_html = ""; 
//var gmarkers = [];

function load() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
  //directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.342339,77.727497), //'mapTypeControlOptions':  
    {style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
      var point = [];
      var point1 = [];
      var path = [];
      //var waypoints = [];

  //var school = document.getElementById("school").value;
  downloadUrl("support.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("point");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("s_name");
      var img5 = markers[i].getAttribute("image_type");
      var school = markers[i].getAttribute("school");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + type + "</b>";

      var image_in = "<img src='http://sundar.lan/tele3/images/"+ img5 + "'/>";

      var icon = type;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        draggable: true,
        icon: icon.icon 
      });
     var name = '<h3>' + "Students :" +'</h3>'+'<h4>' + name +'</h4>';
     //var img = '<h3>' +'<b>' + img5 +  '</b>'+'</h3>';

     bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, name,image_in);
     // var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, type);
     sidebar.appendChild(createSidebarEntry(marker,type));
    }


    for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
      point1[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[j].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[j].getAttribute("lng")));
          var flight = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: point1,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight:2
            });
     flight.setMap(map);
     calcRoute(point1);
     console.log(point1);
    }
  });

  function createSidebarEntry(marker,type) { 
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var html = '<h2>' +'<b>' + type +  '</b>'+'</h2>';
  div.innerHTML = html;
  div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  div.style.marginBottom = '5px'; 
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() { 
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  });
  return div;
}
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker,map, infoWindow, name,image_in) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(name + image_in);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
  });
}

function calcRoute(path) {
    //alert(path);
    for(var k=0; k<path.length-1; k++)   
    { 
    var waypoints = [];
    //alert(k);
    var request = {
        origin:path[k],
        destination:path[k+1],
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING    
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) { 
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        //selected_path =  
    selected_path.concat(results.routes[0].overview_path);
      }
      /*else {
  // alert an error message when the route could nog be calculated.
  if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
    alert('No route could be found between the origin and destination.');
  } else if (status == 'UNKNOWN_ERROR') {
    alert('A directions request could not be processed due to a server error. The 
  request may succeed if you try again.');
  } else if (status == 'REQUEST_DENIED') {
    alert('This webpage is not allowed to use the directions service.');
  } else if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
    alert('The webpage has gone over the requests limit in too short a period of 
  time.');
  } else if (status == 'NOT_FOUND') {
    alert('At least one of the origin, destination, or waypoints could not be 
  geocoded.');
  } else if (status == 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
    alert('The DirectionsRequest provided was invalid.');        
  } else {
    alert("There was an unknown error in your request. Requeststatus: nn"+status);
  }
  }*/
    });
    }
  }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}


//]]>

</script> 

</head>
<body onload="load();">
<!--<div style="width:1200px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; 
border:2px solid #999;"> 
<div align="center" style="width:1200px; height:50px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px; border:3px solid #CCC; color:#0099CC;"><h1>Students stop list's</h1>   
</div>
-->  
<div style="color:#09F; margin-left:550px;"><h2>Students stop list's</h2></div>
<table style="border:#999999 2px solid;"> 
<tbody>  
  <tr id="cm_mapTR">
    <td width="200" valign="top">
     <!--<b>Select:</b><select name="school" id="school" onChange="load();">
     <option value="">--Select--</option>
     <option value="1">BNKN</option>
     <option value="2">SEVENTH DAY</option>
     </select>-->
     <div id="sidebar" style="overflow: auto; height: 520px; font-size: 11px; color:  
 #000;"></div> 
    </td>
    <td> <div id="map" style="overflow: hidden; width: 1150px; height: 520px; 
 border:2px solid #999;"></div> </td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <!--</div>-->
 </body>
 </html>

<markers><line colour="#008800" width="8" html="You clicked the green polyline"><point 
lat="11.3135" lng="77.6658" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Sundar,Arul,Praveen" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3149" lng="77.6687" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Laxman,Dravid,Ganguly" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3174" 
lng="77.6718" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Vijay,Ajith,Surya" image_type="images2.jpg"/>
<point lat="11.3203" lng="77.6751" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Vikram,Ravi,Krishna" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3227" lng="77.6804" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Simbu,Dhanush,Velu" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3264" 
lng="77.6911" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Sham,Jagan,karan" image_type="images2.jpg"/>
<point lat="11.3349" lng="77.7078" type="BUS:0001" s_name="siva,sarvesh,kasi" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3409" lng="77.7171" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Rajan,Rajesh,Pandi" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3481" 
lng="77.7190" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Mugan,Natraj,Balan" image_type="images2.jpg"/>
<point lat="11.3449" lng="77.7269" type="BUS:0001" s_name="karthik,sampath,udhay" 
mage_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3418" lng="77.7283" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Lal,Kannan,Khan" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3578" lng="77.7370" 
type="BUS:0001" s_name="Suresh,Dinesh,Vengadesh" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point 
lat="11.3649" lng="77.7484" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Jay,Prabu,Dana" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3671" lng="77.7649" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Naveen,Muthu,Kumar" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3621" 
lng="77.7808" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Poun,Buvan,Mari" image_type="images2.jpg"/>
<point lat="11.3654" lng="77.8014" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Chandru,Sakthi,Sekar" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3637" lng="77.8262" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Soundar,Balu,Babu" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3657" 
lng="77.8429" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Tamil,Selva,Sasi" image_type="images2.jpg"/>
<point lat="11.3654" lng="77.8560" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Rahim,Ibrahim,Mohmed" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3741" lng="77.8785" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Hari,Nagaraj.Bethana" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.3784" 
lng="77.8947" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Mani,Sheik,Win" image_type="images2.jpg"/><point 
lat="11.3711" lng="77.8908" type="BUS:0001" s_name="Rajesh,Saravanan,Prakash" 
image_type="images2.jpg"/><point lat="11.368994" lng="77.888321" type="BUS:0001" 
s_name="Bethu,Sri,Naveen" image_type="images2.jpg"/></line></markers>
```